# Jenkins Cancel (jobs) from Queue by Label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm freshman in Jenkins. I would like to cancel jobs **by it's own label** (hundreds) from my Queue of tasks given to slaves: `jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getQueue()` 
so i then could do: `items[i].doCancelQueue()`

Currently I only know how to do it, by its **name**: `items[i].task.getFullName()`.

I'm looking for something like this: (when I iterate over Slaves that's just give me list of available labels for a single slave)

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    println('Name: ' + aSlave.name);
    println('getLabelString: ' + aSlave.getLabelString());
}
```

My whole code for deleting jobs by name

```
import hudson.model.*  

def q = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getQueue()   
def items = q.getItems()

if (job_name_fragment == '' && revision == ''){
    println("At least one param is requied")
    return 1
}

def count = 0
for (i=0;i<items.length;i++){  
    if (items[i].task.getName().contains("trunk") || items[i].task.getName().contains("dev")|| items[i].task.getName().contains("Windows")){
        println("Task: " + items[i].task.getName() + " has been skipped")
        continue
    }
    if(job_name_fragment == '' || items[i].task.getFullName().contains(job_name_fragment)){  
        if(revision == '' || items[i].params.contains(revision)){
            println("Task: " + items[i].task.getFullName() + " has been deleted from queue")
            items[i].doCancelQueue()  
            count++;
        }
    }
}
println("")
println("Removed total: " + count + " tasks from queue")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it by myself, if anyone will be interested check:

getAssignedLabel()

in. 
https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.Item.html